# R - lapply() and DataFrame

Tags: r

is it possible to use `lapply()` to dynamically fetch condition and then apply to data frame? For demonstration purpose, I have simplified example

e.g.

```
cond <- list("cyl==6", "mpg >= 21", "hp==110 & cyl==6")
```

I want to apply all conditions on `mtcars` and then store output to new_mtcars

I am currently using `for` loop and not sure if that is an efficient way to do it.

Comment: Using base R `lapply(cond, function(x) subset(mtcars, eval(parse(text = x))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a base R solution to this (EDIT: [Suliman does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133393/r-lapply-and-dataframe/60133495#comment106356105_60133393)), but `parse_expr()` from the `rlang` package would do this:

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

cond <- list("cyl==6", "mpg >= 21", "hp==110 & cyl==6")
filter(mtcars, !! parse_expr(cond[[1]]))

   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
4 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
5 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
6 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
7 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

And to cycle through each condition, using `purrr::map`:

```
purrr::map(cond, ~ filter(mtcars, !! parse_expr(.x)))

[[1]]
   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
4 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
5 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
6 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
7 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6

[[2]]
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
6  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
7  32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
8  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
9  33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
10 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
11 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
12 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
13 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
14 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

[[3]]
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

If you prefer to use `lapply()`, the line `lapply(cond, function(x) filter(mtcars, !! parse_expr(x)))` would have the same output.

If you want a data frame retuned, you can use the following line. Note the usage of `set_names()` to include exactly which condition was used for each line:

```
purrr::map_dfr(purrr::set_names(cond), ~ filter(mtcars, !! parse_expr(.x)), .id = "cond")

               cond  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1            cyl==6 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2            cyl==6 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3            cyl==6 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
4            cyl==6 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
5            cyl==6 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
6            cyl==6 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
7            cyl==6 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
8         mpg >= 21 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
9         mpg >= 21 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
10        mpg >= 21 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
11        mpg >= 21 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
12        mpg >= 21 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
13        mpg >= 21 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
14        mpg >= 21 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
15        mpg >= 21 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
16        mpg >= 21 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
17        mpg >= 21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
18        mpg >= 21 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
19        mpg >= 21 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
20        mpg >= 21 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
21        mpg >= 21 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
22 hp==110 & cyl==6 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
23 hp==110 & cyl==6 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
24 hp==110 & cyl==6 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: I checked  @Suliman solution and that creates output for each condition independently. Could we use other "apply" family functions to pass data frame as input? e.g. mapply.  So after each condition iteration, ouput dataframe will be passed on to next iteration as input.

Comment: I am just trying to assess different solutions on context to vectorized processing vs manual looping.  (as vectorized processing using "apply" family function will be always faster)